# Why this length function undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the length of seconds.If second is one character than add 0 otherwise do nothing.
Here is my Code

```
    <p>Click the button to display the seconds of the time right now.</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      var d = new Date();
      var n = d.getSeconds();
      var z = n.length;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should convert the seconds to string first.

```
  var now = new Date();
  var seconds = d.getSeconds().toString();
```

Then you check the length. The getSeconds gives you a number, and numbers have no length property.

Also I'd recommend using padStart function to append leading zero:

```
  var padded = seconds.padStart(2, '0');
```

Note that padStart is quite a new thing in javascript so check if your target platform supports it and use polyfills if needed.

Comment: Using `.toString()` is more clean and understandable.

Comment: Agreed. Forgot I'm not at work :)

Comment: @AntonRusak you've left your string open: `var padded = seconds.padStart(2, '0');`

Answer (score 0):

The getSeconds function returns a number, which does not have the property length.

If you are trying to get how many characters are in the number you can convert it to a string with .toString()

```
 <p>Click the button to display the seconds of the time right now.</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      var d = new Date();
      var n = d.getSeconds();
      var z = n.toString().length;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getSeconds()` returns an integer not a string. You can achieve what you want by checking if the returned value is `< 10`